# How to change App.config file at run time from textbox value?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, connection-string

I have created a project which has App.config file. This App.config file is fixed. I wanna change connectionString at run time using textbox's value.

Here are two textboxes  `textbox1` & `textbox2`. I want to input in textbox & when I click the button then does it happen?

How could I do that Exactly?

Here is the sample code of App.config file:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`

`<configuration>`

`<connectionStrings>`

`<add name="DBconnection" connectionString="data source=ARIF\SQLEXPRESS;database=Library_Management_System; Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>`

`</connectionStrings>`

`</configuration>`

Comment: Consider using "UserSettings" instead of "ApplicationSettings".

Comment: @User2012384 Please post source code... I am a new developer.. Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I will do it this way:

Properties => Settings => Add new Settings (Make sure Scope is "user")

[image]

Here's how you set the value of ConnectionString:

[image]