# Updating my App.config Connection String from a text box

Tags: c#, visual-studio, configurationmanager

I want the user to be able to edit the connection string, I've set up a file browser dialogue where they can only select .accdb files, and I'm trying to have the save button overwrite the current connection string with the file path from the text box. I've had multiple errors at different times and I've ended up with a setup that seems tantalisingly close to working but I have a NullReferenceException error which says "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object". Hopefully this is a newbie mistake.

```
var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(@"\\Mac\Home\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\tiddlywinks\tiddlywinks\App.config");
var section = (ConnectionStringsSection)configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings");
section.ConnectionStrings["tiddlywinksDatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source ='" + filePathTextBox.Text + "'; Persist Security Info=False;";
configuration.Save();
```

This is the code that I have atm. Can anyone help?
Also, is there a way to achieve the same without having to tell the program where App.config is, surely Visual Studios knows where it's own config files are?

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980440/update-app-config-system-net-setting-at-runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that this way:
You go to your solution properties

> Properties => Settings => Add new Settings
>
> (Make sure Scope is "user")

and add a new sitting for your connection string, let's call it : `ConnectionString`

like mentioned in this post:
[Applications sittings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484340/how-to-change-app-config-file-at-run-time-from-textbox-value)

then all you have to do is

```
Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString = TextBoxConnectionString.Text
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Give it a try, Hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you, this worked. My only annoyance is that the stupid reports thing created a database connection thing and I thought it might be a good idea to use that rather than the string that I was using throughout. Not to worry though, because the reports don't work well anyway so I'm going to take them out.

Answer (score 0):

user cannot change application setting at run time.
It can be modified only at design time.
Use User settings for this.

How to : [Using Application Settings and User Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Regards